# $G$ is residually finite if and only if $N = \{ 1_G \}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

I'm reading about reasidually finite groups and has a question about a proof that was given.

Here are the definitions that are contained in the reading:

1. A group $G$ is called *residually finite* if for each element $g \in G$, $g \neq 1_G$, there exists a finite group $F$ and a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to F$ such that $\varphi(g) \neq 1_F$.
2. Given a group $G$, the intersection of all subgroups of finite index of $G$ is called the *residual subgroup* of $G$.

Here are a few facts I understand and need not to be proved.

Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ denote the residual subgroup of $G$. Then:

3. $N$ is equal to the intersection of all normal subgroups of finite index in $G$.
4. $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Finally here is the proof that was given but I need help understanding:

Claim: $G$ is residually finite if and only if $N = \{ 1_G \}$

Proof: Suppose that $G$ is residually finite. Let $g \in G$ such that $g \neq 1_G.$ Then there exist a finite group $F$ and a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to F$ such that $\varphi(g) \neq 1_F$ .
Thus $g \notin \text{Ker}(\varphi).$ As the group $G / \text{Ker}(\varphi)$ is isomorphic to $F$, the subgroup
$\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ is of finite index in $G$. This shows that $N = \{1_G \}.$

Conversely, suppose that $N = \{1 _G \}.$ Let $g \in G$ such that $g \neq 1_G$. By (3),
we can find a normal subgroup of finite index $K \subset G$ such that $g \notin K.$ If
$\varphi: G \to G / K$ is the canonical homomorphism, we have $\varphi(g) \neq 1_{G / K}.$ This
shows that $G$ is residually finite. $\square$

Here are my questions:

1. By the first isomorphism theorem, we know that $G / \text{Ker}(\varphi)$ is isomorphic to $F$, however it is not clear to me  why the subgroup
   $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ is of finite index in $G$ and why this shows that $N = \{1_G \}$?
2. I do not understand the statement "By (3),
   we can find a normal subgroup of finite index $K \subset G$ such that $g \notin K.$"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $G/\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)\equiv F$, then $|G/\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)|=|F|<\infty$.

Comment: Use `*text*` for *text*.

Comment: @kabenyuk yes that is clear now, but how can we then conclude that $N$ is trivial?

Comment: We have proved that $g \not\in \ker \varphi$, and so $g \not\in N$. That's true for all $g \ne 1$, so $N$ is trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you. Could you possibly shed some light regarding my second question.

Comment: This follows immediately from (3) and the fact that $g \not\in N$.